# Graphic/web design approach to deal between UI design and front-end development

Tags: website-design, css, interface-design, html

I have to search for a UI designer/front end developer to build my website out of a set of wireframes.

I noticed this process is very fragmented due to complexity. What would be the best approach?

1) a "GREAT" UI designer to provide only the layout .psd, then I have a front-end developer to work on it; or

2) a "GOOD" UI designer capable to do a "GOOD" front-end development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this question can be answered objectively, both options depend on the person you choose.

Both UI and development are getting increasingly broader. A great UI designer needs to know about development, and a good web developer should be comfortable around usability.

If the functionality of the site is complex, you will need a developer that specializes in certain technologies (javascript, php, .net), but it will all depend on what exactly you want to achieve.

These questions might be of help:

- [Steps between Wireframe / UI design for web development](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20777/steps-between-wireframe-ui-design-for-web-development?rq=1)
- [What are the most important qualities to look for when hiring a great mobile UI designer for a consumer-facing Internet startup?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11388/what-are-the-most-important-qualities-to-look-for-when-hiring-a-great-mobile-ui/11395#11395)

Comment: I understand now, thanks Yisela. Let say that a UI designer created the layout .psd. The correct approach is a designer providing the code (HTML/CSS) or it's related to the developer?

Comment: If you hire a designer to give you a PSD, it's most likely you will have the developer writing the code. Although a lot of web designers do their projects directly in HTML/CSS. But this is my opinion/experience, I'm sure others here will have different ones (that will get posted as answers during the day).